# Explain how this function removes the negative values

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  // Don't show a false ID to this bouncer.

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!arr[i]) {
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            i = i-1;
        }
    }
    return arr;

}

bouncer([7, "ate", "", false, 9]);
```

I don't understand how the exclamation mark works in the conditional. I know it's used to negate but I'm not understanding how.

Comment: *if not arr[i]* ...

Comment: `alert (!false);
alert (!null);
alert (!undefined);` ...

Comment: @per svensson no it means not...

Comment: @per svensson thats right. But *! means falsy* isnt

Comment: You could simplify your bouncer function to `return arr.filter(e => e);`

Comment: As @Jonasw said in his answer it's a matter of Truthy and Falsy. Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Glossary/Truthy) link for further information

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. For some reason I couldn't get my head around the logic of what it actually said.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (!arr[i]) {
```

Means basically *if not arr[i]*. This works as values in js are either truthy or falsy, so just falsy values would pass the upper condition (*if not falsy === true*):

```
null,undefined,"",0,false
```